# Ghostscript installed but not found RGhost::Config::GS[:path]='/path/to/my/gs'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, runtime-error, ghostscript

I've been trying for a few hours now solve this problem and I looked everywhere for a solution and I did not find one. I'm trying to run a spec test for my project and I have the following error coming up:

```
RuntimeError:
 
   Ghostscript not found in your system environment (linux-gnu).
   Install it and set the variable RGhost::Config::GS[:path] with the executable.
   Example: RGhost::Config::GS[:path]='/path/to/my/gs' #unix-style
    RGhost::Config::GS[:path]="C:\\gs\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"  #windows-style
```

And I do try to put `RGhost::Config::GS[:path]='/usr/local/bin/gs'` and it returns:

```
bash: RGhost::Config::GS[:path]=/usr/local/bin/gs: No such file or directory
```

but ghostscript is installed, I did everything (make, sudo make install, etc etc) and when I run `gs -v` it returns:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.26 (2018-11-20)
Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

When I use the user interface and search for "gs" in the "Files" application, it is found in `/home/marcelle/projects/ghostscript-9.26/bin/gs` and I also tried:

```
RGhost::Config::GS[:path]='/home/marcelle/projects/ghostscript-9.26/bin/gs'
```

and it returns the same error:

```
bash: RGhost::Config::GS[:path]=/home/marcelle/projects/ghostscript-9.26/bin/gs: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to delete ghostscript from my notebook with autoremove and purge and installed it again using what I mentioned before (./configure, make, sudo make install), restarted the notebook, the terminal and nothing.

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: This looks like a ruby question. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rghost/0.9.7/RGhost/Config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out a solution. Looking for the code for the Rghost, what I saw in its spec is that the path expected was different than the path the ghostscript really is.
When I run whereis or which on my terminal, it returns:

```
which gs
/usr/local/bin/gs
```

So I was trying to point to this path. But seeing the spec test for Rghost which I found on [github for Rghost](https://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost/blob/20bd944bcef30a78400516c78f3775bfc5d59ae0/spec/rghost_config_spec.rb), we can see that it expects /usr/bin/gs:

```
 it 'should detect linux env properly' do
    RbConfig::CONFIG.should_receive(:[]).twice.with('host_os').and_return('linux')
    File.should_receive(:exists?).with('/usr/bin/gs').and_return(true)
    RGhost::Config.config_platform
    RGhost::Config::GS[:path].should == '/usr/bin/gs'
  end
```

So it expects /usr/bin and not /usr/local/bin.
Then I just copied to that path and the spec ran with no problems anymore:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin
```

Comment: Note: I think a more common practice in Linux is to create a symlink rather than to copy the file: `ln -s /usr/local/bin/gs /usr/bin/gs`.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with Ruby at all, but I also got this error when using asciidoctor, which uses rghost for the PDF generation.

The command `RGhost::Config::GS[:path]='/path/to/my/gs'` mentioned in the error is not a shell command, which is why `bash` couldn't handle it. However, to me it wasn't immediately clear what to do with this command either. I expected an easy way to set this variable somewhere, but couldn't find it.

What worked for me was searching the **rghost.rb** file, which is where this variable is set and can be changed. In Windows, it was located in `C:\Ruby30-x64\lib\ruby\gems\3.0.0\gems\rghost-0.9.7\lib\rghost.rb`.

In this file, I added the following line, which solved the problem:

```
RGhost::Config::GS[:path]="C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.55.0\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"
```

NB: the mentioned paths can be different for everyone, so make sure to use that paths that are valid for your system.